# External display color problem

Tags: display, bootcamp, color

So I have a weird problem...

[image]

This only happens when I boot into macOS (10.14.4), when I boot into Win10 via bootcamp, everything is perfect and no color issues at all.

So this rules out any hardware problems.

I am not too familiar with macOS so maybe its just a user setting somewhere but the color options under display don't do anything to solve the issue.

Suggestions?

Comment: See if [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201177#3) fixes your issue.

Comment: Do you have System preferences > Accessibility > Display > Invert Colors checked?

Comment: The screen on top is the MBP and its just mirroring to the bottom displays atm. So Invert Colors isnt checked and it's not a brightness or contrast issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix! It has to do with the EDID settings.

https://michaelcivitillo.com/overriding-edid-on-osx-for-external-monitors/